# CSS Menu hover - item

Tags: css

Hover element - how Can I do something like this in attachment. This triangular as element after or is better way (simple)?

Width is diffrent of each element.

Main problem is in triangular, should I populate width of background? Position left?

```
Please see http://jsfiddle.net/jachu/AB3wx/
```

[image]

Comment: Which is exactly the problem? You want to set the triangle in the bottom right corner of the menu item?

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could do this (with just CSS) is by having a triangular image and when you hover you trigger it to show in CSS.

**See this**: http://jsfiddle.net/cranavvo/ze8GQ/

**10x10 Triangle**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgsIr.png

```
ul#navigation>li:hover{
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgsIr.png') no-repeat 100% 100% black;   
}
```